# Include package view in my main view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have a package in my Laravel project that has a view of it's own. I need to include that view in the main view of my project. My package is named as Tkabir\Somepackage. In my project's config/app.php, I have included the service provider for the package as

```
'providers' => [
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Tkabir\Somepackage\SomeServiceProvider::class,
]
```

and also included alias for package's facade as

```
'aliases' => [
    /*
     */
    'Somepackage' => Tkabir\Somepackage\Facade\Somepackage::class,
]
```

But still, when I try to include the view from the package in my main view like this:

```
@include('Somepackage::welcome')
```

...where welcome.blade.php is the blade view file in my package, I get the following error displayed:

> ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 112:
>   No hint path defined for [Somepackage]. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel->projects\test_package\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

What may seem to be the problem here?

Here's the link to my package in Github, if anyone needs to see the files: [mypackage](https://github.com/tkabir/mypackage)

Comment: Also, can somebody with a high rep please edit the title of my post to make more sense? I started writing the title but then totally forgot to finish it -_-

Comment: better to publish your package views to laravel resource directory it will be easy access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@include` includes a view. You're calling in a method for a class.

You're including configurations correctly with

```
$this->publishes([
    .'/Config/somepackage.php' => config_path('somepackage.php'),
], 'config');
```

You need to do the same thing for your views in your service provider's `boot()` method for views: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages#views | Header: Publishing Views

You also need to run `php artisan vendor:publish` just as you would for configurations, and include your view in with `@include`

Take a look at the link I gave for full documentation on building packages in Laravel

Comment: Thanks a lot! Followed exactly what you said, and it worked like a charm! However, I have some variables in the view of the package that were defined from controller/config. So in order to use those variables in my main view, I would also have to publish the controllers and config files from the package, right?

Comment: It's probably best to leave controllers with Laravel, and just make a class in your package instead. Then call the class in one of the controllers that loads the view you need to include, then pass in that data.